# migrate a VM from Server 2012 to Windows 8 pro

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, migration

is it possible to migrate a VM from Server 2012 to Windows 8 pro (both in the same domain)

Live migration does not seem to be a feature on Windows 8 (only on Server 2012) and when I try to move it from the Hyper-v console I get:
"The destination computer is not configured for live migration of virtual machines."
The migration does not have to be live, I can shut down the VM but I'm looking for a simple solution.

The files associated with the VM are on a local (non shared) disk on the server and they would go to a local folder on the workstation. PowerShell tips are welcome.

Comment: You could try exporting and importing the VM. Additionally, you could copy the files from the server to the workstation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a full export of the VM and import it on the Windows 8 machine.

Or, if you want the process to involve less down time, you could use storage migration to move the VM's files to somewhere the Windows 8 machine can see and then point the new host at the configuration files and import.

Comment: how do I export configuration only on Hyper-v 3?

Comment: I misspoke.  I've edited my response.  You can just import the config files directly.